# Issue serving Swagger file in a containerised go app

Tags: go, swagger

I'm currently writing an app in go. I've never done this in go before so please be patient. I'm trying to happily serve my swagger doc via docker.

I'm using redoc/redocly but when I containerise my app, I can no longer access the endpoint I've configured to serve the swagger doc.

Here is the code regarding swagger I have within my app:

```
sm := mux.NewRouter()
opts := middleware.RedocOpts{SpecURL: "/swagger.yaml"}
sh := middleware.Redoc(opts, nil)

sm.Handle("/docs", sh)
sm.Handle("/swagger.yaml", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./")))

s := &http.Server{
    Addr:         ":8080",           // configure the bind address
    Handler:      sm,                // set the default handler
    ReadTimeout:  1 * time.Second,   // max read time out for client
    WriteTimeout: 1 * time.Second,   // max time to write response to client
    IdleTimeout:  120 * time.Second, // max time for connections using TCP keep-alive
}

go func() {
    err := s.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}()
```

Apparently I can serve static files using in-built fileserver in go-lang that I've tried to do.

The above works as intended when I run the app from within VS Code.

However when I containerize the code and run the docker container, I don't see the swagger doc served in the nice UI when I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/docs`.

When I check network tools in my web browser e.g Chrome it shows the following error:

> **Error: Failed to load http://localhost:8080/swagger.yaml: 404 Not Found**

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Do I need to do make modifications to the code or the `Dockerfile` so I can get redocly to serve the file.

**UPDATE**
I'm sharing my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.16-alpine AS builder

# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
CGO_ENABLED=0 \
GOOS=linux \
GOARCH=amd64

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

WORKDIR /dist

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp /build/main .

# Build a small image
FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder /dist/main /

EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run when starting the container
ENTRYPOINT ["/main"]
```

Comment: How did you run the docker container? Does it work from the container IP itself, instead of localhost?

Comment: I ran the docker container using docker run command: docker run -d -it -p 8080:8080 --name=my-api. The swagger aspect doesn't work when running the container so not sure what is going on. I did use container IP as well but that hasn't worked: `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/docs`

Comment: It is likely that your container doesn't have all the necessary files

Comment: I've now included my Dockerfile. Am i missing something from there?

Comment: It looks like you only have the go binary in that image, not the swagger stuff.

Comment: @BurakSerdar are there any examples that you can share with me please that I can refer to that demonstrate how to include the swagger stuff in my docker file in order to get it to work?